# Firebase: Enabling 'Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address' only works for newly created accounts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to apply the setting 'Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address' for all accounts in an existing firebase project.

I am trying to create a new account, and this new account has the same email as an existing account that was created before the setting was enabled. I expected the account to be created, however, firebase tells me that the email exists. I do not face this error if i create multiple new accounts with the same email, after enabling the setting.

I am also facing the additional restriction of using the firebase-auth only, not firebase-admin, so we cannot delete the account and create a new account on the backend. I've researched but did not find a suitable answer, or found anyone else facing this issue, so far:

[Firebase Allowing Multiple Accounts from Same Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916776/firebase-allowing-multiple-accounts-from-same-email-address)

[How to handle multiple sign in methods for the same user in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391942/how-to-handle-multiple-sign-in-methods-for-the-same-user-in-firebase?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The "Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address" setting applies per project and is not tracked for each account. So it sounds like you either didn't change the correct setting, or something else is wrong (i.e. are you sure you set it on the correct project?) It's hard to say more without seeing steps with which we can all reproduce the problem (and I must admit I haven't changed this setting in quite some time).

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/r5nMSr5rIpw